# So I'm trying to workout my app so that the user can log into it by using google account

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sanity

So I'm trying to workout my app so that the user can log into it by using google account.
I'm using sanity and the login button works and the data is being written in the sanity database. However I'm not sure that the app is fetching the data from the database properly.
Considering after the user logs in to the app the user is redirected to homepage where there is supposed to show the users google profile picture.
This is ReactJS with tailwindcss and sanity.
Here is my code..

Login component:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { GoogleLogin } from '@react-oauth/google';
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';

import Logo from '../Assets/Logo/Logo1.png'
import { client } from '../client'

import img1 from '../Assets/LoginPage/1.jpg';
import img2 from '../Assets/LoginPage/2.jpeg';
import img3 from '../Assets/LoginPage/3.jpeg';
import img4 from '../Assets/LoginPage/4.jpg';
import img5 from '../Assets/LoginPage/5.jpg';
import img6 from '../Assets/LoginPage/6.jpeg';
import img7 from '../Assets/LoginPage/7.jpeg';
import img8 from '../Assets/LoginPage/8.jpeg';
import img9 from '../Assets/LoginPage/9.jpg';

const Login = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const responseGoogle = async (response) => {
    const decoded = { name:String, picture:String, sub:String } = jwt_decode(response.credential);
    const { name, picture, sub } = decoded;
    const user = {
      _id: sub,
      _type: 'user',
      userName: name,
      image: picture,
    }

    client.createIfNotExists(user)
      .then(() => {
        navigate('/', {replace: true})
      })

    // console.log(decoded)
  };

  return (
    <div className='bg-gray-800 h-screen justify-start' >
      <div className='md:fixed md:grid md:grid-cols-3 md:gap-0 flex flex-col'>
        <div className=''>
            <img src={img1} alt="image 1" />
        </div>
        <div className=''>
          <img src={img2} alt="image 2" />
        </div>
        <div className=''>
          <img src={img5} alt="image 5" />
        </div>
        <div className=''>
          <img src={img6} alt="image 6" />
        </div>
        <div className='-mt-[5vh]'>
          <img src={img4} alt="image 4" />
        </div>
        <div className='md:mt-[2.5vh]'>
          <img src={img8} alt="image 9" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className='absolute flex flex-col justify-center items-center top-0 bottom-0 left-0 right-0 bg-blackOverlay'>
        <div className='fixed px-[5em] py-[4em] bg-gray-700 border-4 border-mainColor rounded-xl justify-center'>
          <div className='flex justify-center items-center -mt-[4em]'>
            <div className='p-1 my-2 bg-gray-500 rounded-[75%]'>
              <img src={Logo} width="60px" alt="Logo" />
            </div>
            <div className='text-[2em] ml-[5px] font-[Fredoka_One, cursive]'>
              <h1><span className='text-white'>Share</span><span className='text-gray-400'>Smile</span></h1>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className='flex justify-center mt-[8em] scale-150'>
            <GoogleLogin 
              onSuccess={(response) => responseGoogle(response)}
              onError={() => console.log('error')}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Login
```

Home container:

```js
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react'
import { GoogleOAuthProvider } from '@react-oauth/google'
import { HiMenu } from 'react-icons/hi'
import { AiFillCloseCircle } from 'react-icons/ai'
import { Link, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'

import { Sidebar, UserProfile } from '../components'
import Pins from './Pins'
import { userQuery } from '../utils/data'
import { client } from '../client'
import Logo from '../Assets/Logo/Logo1.png'

const Home = () => {
  const [toggleSidebar, setToggleSidebar] = useState(false);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
  const userInfo = localStorage.getItem('user') !== 'undefined' ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')) : localStorage.clear();

  useEffect(() => {
    const query = userQuery(userInfo?.googleId);

    client.fetch(query)
      .then((data) => {
        setUser(data[0]);
      })
  }, [])
  

  return (
      <div className='flex bg-gray-700 md:flex-row flex-col h-screen transition-height duration-75 ease-out'>
        <div className='hidden md:flex h-screen flex-initial'>
          <Sidebar />
        </div>
        <div className='flex md:hidden flex-row'>
          <HiMenu fontSize={40} className='cursor-pointer' onClick={() => setToggleSidebar(false)}/>
          <Link to="/">
            <img src={Logo} alt="Logo" className='w-10 p-0.5 bg-gray-500 rounded-[75%]' />
          </Link>
          <Link to={`user-profile/${user?._id}`}>
            <img src={user?.image} alt="Profile" className='w-10' />
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

data.js utility:

```js
export const userQuery = (userId) => {
    const query = `*[_type == "user" && _id == '${userId}']`;
    return query;
}
```

and this is App.js

```js
import {React, useEffect} from 'react'
import { Routes, Route, useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';
import { GoogleOAuthProvider } from '@react-oauth/google';

import Login from './components/Login';
import Home from './container/Home';

const App = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    const User = localStorage.getItem('user') !== 'undefined' ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')) : localStorage.clear();

    if (!User) navigate('/Login');
  }, []);

  return (
    <GoogleOAuthProvider clientId={`${process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_API_TOKEN}`}>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="/*" element={<Home />} />
      </Routes>
    </GoogleOAuthProvider>
  )
}

export default App
```

Anyone knows what is wrong here?
I'm going after tutorial on social media app by JavaScriptMastery on youtube.
And considering google changed it's login authentication I had to go to another video that he covered that but translate a part of the code from typescript to javascript.

Comment: You said "I'm not sure that the app is fetching the data from the database properly" and asked "anyone knows what is wrong here," but I'm not seeing any errors or output suggesting this might be the case. Would you be able to clarify that part, please?

Comment: @GeoffBall The thing is once the user is reidrected to the home page on the mobile version of the app next to the logo up top is supposed to show the profile picture of the user taken from google. however instead i get an alt text.

Comment: also this is what i get when I inspect in the browser:
client:101 Uncaught TypeError: String is not a function

Comment: I would look at revising this line: `const decoded = { name:String, picture:String, sub:String } = jwt_decode(response.credential);` It's not valid JavaScript and isn't included in the codebase of the tutorial you mentioned. Do you make any progress if you remove `{ name:String, picture:String, sub:String } =`?

Comment: well it moved forward just like before removing them but the picture is not showing anyway.

this might look very noobish but the original code was:

export const createOrGetUser = async (response: any) => {
    const decoded: { name: string picture: string sub: string } = jwt_decode(response.credential);
    const {name, picture, sub} = decoded;
    const user = {
      _id: sub,
      _type: 'user',
      userName: name,
      image: picture,
    };

But I kinda translated it from TypeScript

Comment: essentially i think that const decoded properties need to be made into strings otherwise the database wont recognize them and nothing will happen. When I hover my mouse over them they show as for example name: any. And Idk how to make them into strings with plain javascript or react for that matter.

Comment: The `:String` parts are TypeScript (though String should be lowercase) and need to come out, and you’re destructuring on the next line anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of  the `sub` google credential use the `aud` cred in both Login page and Home page.

Also this block of code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const query = userQuery(userInfo?.googleId);
```

Should look like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const query = userQuery(userInfo?.aud);
```

This is quite an old question though hope it helps :)

Comment: Well this was some time ago. I actually managed to solve it way back, turned out it was a typo in the query. But thank you nontheless